# IF statment for checking if arecord is working inside a shell script no responding well

Tags: shell, cron, pgrep

I wrote a script that should check if the arecord command line audio recorder is not working, and if so it should start it.
With the help of cron, I want to verify that I'm recording within a specific time frame. Thid is because sometimes the arecord stop without any warning.

Here is my script (a shell executable file) I run with cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
dateis=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
if [pgrep -x "arecord" >/dev/null]
then 
    
else 
    arecord -v -f dat -r 48 -D hw:1,0 -d 200 -c 2 | lame -r -h - record-$dateis.mp3
fi
```

For some reason, even when the arecord is recording, it tries to start another instance of arecord. On the command line, the pgrep is indicating properly. But for some reason it won't stop and would ignore the if statment. It starts recording even though it is running at the same moment.

Hope I made this issue clear.

Comment: `[pgrep -x "arecord" >/dev/null]` should attempt to open a file named `/dev/null]` and execute a command named `[pgrep` - both of which should result in errors. Are you sure that's **exactly** what your script contains?

Comment: paste your code into https://shellcheck.net for help with syntax errors.

Comment: thanks @glennjackman ! a great tool!!

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need

```
#!/bin/sh
dateis=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
if pgrep -x "arecord" >/dev/null
then
    :
else
    arecord -v -f dat -r 48 -D hw:1,0 -d 200 -c 2 | lame -r -h - record-$dateis.mp3
fi
```

I've tested this, it did what you want.

Comment: did it (thanks) and still - it continues to start a new recording before the arecord stop the previus one...

Comment: What does "file $(which arecord)" give you?

Comment: interesting... when i use "file $(which arecord)" i get "usr/bin/arecord: symbolic link to aplay" and when i do "fle $(which aplay)" i get all the detals

Comment: Could be the reason "pgrep -x" doesn't work.

Comment: O.K. but i really don't understand it. cause i can see the proccess. when i do "pidof arecord"  get a number (the pid prosumably) and when i do pidof "aplay" i get nothing...

Comment: and for the record. on a different machine (my mint laptop) it's the same - "file $(which arecord)" gives me the same output as so "file $(which aplay)"

Comment: The same?  arecord is a symbolic link, but aplay should be an executable.

Comment: Would you show your current script in your question?  Preferably without syntax errors, eg. empty line between then and else.